# Why doesn't restoring in-app purchase not work on iOS anymore?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have iOS apps that have worked for years with non-consumable in-app purchases that users could restore. Now it no longer works. What changed or what am I doing wrong?

I call

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`

In the store observer, it used to go here

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {   
    // never gets here  
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {   
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {   
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:   
                // used to go here, no longer does
```

I added this and it goes here with 0 transactions

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {   
    // goes here with [queue.transactions count] == 0
```

Comment: The implication is that the user is mistaken about having already performed this purchase, i.e. there is nothing to restore.

Comment: There is definitely a previous purchase. If I try to purchase as new, it says I've already purchased it, would I like to get it for free.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: No, still doesn't work

Comment: Are you testing via a TestFlight build?

Comment: Somehow it just started working, I didn't change anything.

Comment: Yay! Of course this leaves us none the wiser. Did Apple break and repair the back end? We'll never know, because Apple would never admit to making a mistake.